# How to Disable Rotate Gesture From TranslateZoomRotateBehavior

Tags: c#, wpf

TranslateZoomRotateBehavior control has the following supported gestures:

- All
- TranslateX
- TranslateY
- Translate
- Rotate
- Scale
- None

I would like to use all gestures except for Rotate. Is there a way to override the control?

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. You just need to set multiple values from the SupportedGestures property:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ei:TranslateZoomRotateBehavior MaximumScale="3" MinimumScale="1" 
        SupportedGestures="Scale, Translate" ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```